"pointer value used where a floating-point was expected", but variable is of type void *
I am confused by following error message. I don't know where the floating-point comes from here.
error: pointer value used where a floating-point was expected
  279 |       ret_value = (void *)((IntFuncWithThreeArg)closure->bound_func)((int)args_values[0], (double)args_values[1], (int)args_values[2]);

The above expression is a call to a ffi closure which returns an int with following type:
typedef int (*IntFuncWithThreeArg)(int, double, int);

The ret_value variable is defined as a void *. And args_values is obviously an array of void * which holds different types.
Is there something wrong with it or the problem most be somewhere else in the code?
EDIT:
I will try to minimize the important parts of the code (omitting the implementation details of unrelated things), but compiling a minimal example for a polymorphic object implementation would be nothing close of "minimal".
The closures are called and stored inside objects:
typedef void (*GeneralFunc)();

typedef struct {
  char *name;
  char *ret_t;
  char **args_t;
  uint8_t args_n;
  void *bound_func;
} ClosureBinding;

ClosureBinding *bind_closure(char *ret_t, char *name, GeneralFunc closure_p, char *args_t[], const uint8_t args_n, void *stream) {
  ffi_cif cif;
  ffi_type *args[args_n];
  ffi_closure *closure;
  void *bound_func;
  _Bool failed;

  failed = 1;
  closure = NULL;

  closure = ffi_closure_alloc(sizeof(ffi_closure), &bound_func);
  if (closure) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < args_n; ++i)
      args[i] = strcmp(args_t[i], "int") == 0 ? &ffi_type_sint : strcmp(args_t[i], "double") == 0 ? &ffi_type_double : &ffi_type_schar;

    if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, ABI, args_n, strcmp(ret_t, "int") == 0 ? &ffi_type_sint : strcmp(ret_t, "double") == 0 ? &ffi_type_double : &ffi_type_schar, args) == FFI_OK)
      if (ffi_prep_closure_loc(closure, &cif, closure_p, stream, bound_func) == FFI_OK)
        failed = 0;
  }

  return new_closure_binding(name, ret_t, args_t, args_n, bound_func);
}

[...]

typedef struct Object_t {
  ClosureBinding **closures;
  uint8_t closures_n;

  void *(*call)(struct Object_t *self, int index, ...);
} Object;

void *call(Object *self, int index, ...);

Object *new_object(const uint8_t closures_n) {
  Object *self     = (Object *)malloc(sizeof(Object));

  self->call       = call;
  self->closures   = malloc(sizeof(ClosureBinding) *closures_n);
  self->closures_n = closures_n;

  return self;
}

The most important probably are the implementation details of the call function.
typedef int (*IntFuncWithThreeArg)(int, double, int);

void *call(Object *self, int index, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, index);

  ClosureBinding *closure = self->closures[index];

  printf("Call the '%s' closure\n", closure->name);

  // Get the closure argument values from variadic arguments
  void *args_values[closure->args_n];

  for (int i = 0; i < closure->args_n; ++i) {
    char *arg;

    printf("Before argument allocation\n");
    arg = closure->args_t[i];
    if (!strcmp(arg, "int")) {
      int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
      *p = va_arg(args, int);
      args_values[i] = p;
    } else if (!strcmp(arg, "double") || !strcmp(arg, "float")) {
      double *p = malloc(sizeof(double));
      *p = va_arg(args, double);
      args_values[i] = p;
    }
  }

  void *ret_value;

  if (!strcmp(closure->ret_t, "int")) {
    if (closure->args_n == 3) {
      ret_value = (void *)((IntFuncWithThreeArg)closure->bound_func)(*(int *)args_values[0], *(double *)args_values[1], *(int *)args_values[2]);
    } else {
      ret_value = (void *)-1;
      fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Attempt to execute an INT type closure but argument's type is unregistered\n");
    }
  } else {
    ret_value = (void *)-1;
    fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Return type unregistered\n");
  }

  va_end(args);
  return ret_value;
}


Please show code instead of describing it.

You say the target variable is void *ret_value, but the function returns int not a pointer.

Aside: I'd generally call casting an int to a void * a red flag (ret_value). Your question: If "args_values is . . . an array of void *" and index 1 is actually a pointer to double, then your second argument should be: *(double *)args_values[1].    I could be wrong, but my impression is that you are making multiple errors all due to forgetting the distinction between a pointer and what it points to.

Your first & third arguments have the same issue, the compiler just didn't warn you about it. So the handling of the return value and all 3 fcn arguments appear to me to be suffering from the same issue.

C does not define conversions between void * and floating types, so (double)args_values[1] has undefined behavior.  I imagine that's probably what the diagnostic is complaining about.

Also, although C does allow conversions from void * to integer types and back, that doesn't mean they are a good or useful thing for you to be doing in your code. void * is not an "Any" type.

@AviBerger Thank you, I made the casting to double wrong, that's true. I know though that casting void * to int is shady, but what do you think I should do when I have a function that calls generic closures from an object's array? Linux C library does similar thing to implement the buffer e.g. for the read function.

@RetiredNinja But gentelmen, this question is not much about the code, rather about how to cast those values appropriately.

@JohnBollinger Yes, C does not define conversion from void * to float. But it does from void * to double.

No, @siery, the C language spec does not define conversions between void * and any floating type, float, double, or long double.  Your implementation might provide such conversions as an extension, but the language spec does not define it as an allowed conversion, unlike conversions between void * and integer types, or between void * and other object-pointer types.

@JohnBollinger Hmm.. maybe that's the problem I have when porting this piece of code to other platform. Can you prompt me to the source of this information. In C one can assign int * to void * with no cast, right? That's why compiler does not complain about the int?

@siery, you can convert among any object pointer types.  That includes void *, int *, double *, float *, struct any_struct *, and more.  You cannot convert between pointer types and floating types such as double.  Type double * is a pointer type, not a floating type.  Perhaps you're not appreciating that pointer types are distinct types from the types they point to.


And args_values is obviously an array of void * which holds different types.

You are casting a void * to a double, just like the following:
int main( void ) {
   void *vp;
   double d = (double)vp;
}

<source>:3:4: error: pointer value used where a floating-point was expected
    3 |    double d = (double)vp;
      |    ^~~~~~

This is undefined behaviour, thus the warning.

Is args_values[1] actually a pointer to a double? If so, you should be using
*(double *)args_values[1]

If not, you should be using a union type rather than void *.
Similar changes should be adopted for the int values as well.

Yes, args_values[1] is a pointer to a double. I should have mentioned it. Thank you for your deduction, I forgot about the dereference. Well, I am learning a lot as working on this project.

Well, I know I shall ideally use the union for argument types, but for now I tried to change it to: ret_value = (void *)((IntFuncWithThreeArg)closure->bound_func)(*(int *)args_values[0], *(double *)args_values[1], *(int *)args_values[2]). This now gives me a segmentation fault at runtime.

@siery segmentation fault would make sense if John Bollinger's suspecion re an "Any" type was correct. I was presuming that your pointers were really pointers. Is your args_values[1] a pointer to where a real double is in memory or a piece of memory that you are telling the compiler is one thing and your are trying to jam something else into?

@Avi Berger, The OP confirmed "args_values[1] is a pointer to a double". But yeah, they should double-check that it's actually a pointer. (e.g. double d = 1.2; args_values[1] = &d;, not args_values[1] = d;.) In any case, there's insufficient information to discuss this further.

@ikegami I know. That is what it should be, but OP's segmentation fault comment encourages me to doubt that. And MS has done stuff like that with the Windows API.

@Avi Berger, I didn't say that is should be a pointer to a double; I said the OP already said it is.

@AviBerger I have updated the code that's responsible for calling the closures. BTW. I think the end of high school is a good time to grow up from the impression of being the main protagonist. I agree that I should focus less on the griefers and more on the valuable commisions, my bad, but you most agree that scads of commentators mainly commit hate and wrong informations. But well, I guess that's internet today.

@siery actually, my bad. From that code, it looks like ikegami and you are right and you now have those arguments right & they are not the cause of the segfault I thought they might be. Don't know what is.
